# Get notified when NSOperation has failed

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I'm using a background operation to make a URL request.
How can I be notified if the operation has returned with an error and then re add the same operation type to the queue to retry?

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSNotification for that. Create a Notification and post it when your request failed. Listen for the notification in your controller.

Example below.

Add a Listener for Notification:

```
NSString *notificationName = @"RequestFailed";

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] 
addObserver:self
selector:@selector(failedRequestNotification:) 
name:notificationName 
object:nil];
```

Posting a Notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:notificationName object:nil userInfo:nil]
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, my issue is more with being notified when the operation has failed as opposed to being returned with no error.